# Formal definitions for group theory

Tags: group-theory, definition

Here are some proposed formal definitions in group theory for group, subgroup and left cosets for use in a computerized, formal system. Do they conform to the standard definitions? Online notes seem a bit vague for my purposes. I want to be sure I have captured the essence of these concepts before proceeding with my project.

**Group**

$\forall G,*: [Group(G,*) \iff \forall a,b\in G: a*b\in G$

$\land \forall a,b,c\in G: (a*b)*c=a*(b*c)$

$\land \exists e\in G: [\forall x\in G: [e*x=x \land x*e=x]$

$\land \forall a \in G: \exists b\in G: [b*a=e \land a*b=e]]]$

**Subgroup $H\le G$**

$\forall G, H, *:[Group(G,*) \implies [H\le G \iff Group(H,*) \land H\subseteq G]]$

**Left Coset $L(a,H,G,*,x)$**

$\forall G, H, *, x: [Group(G,*)\land H\le G \land x\in G$

$ \implies \forall a: L(a,H,G,*,x) \iff \forall b:[b\in a \iff \exists c\in H: b=x*c]]$

where $L(a,H,G,*,x)$ means $a$ is the left coset of $H$ in $G$ wrt $x$.

---

**EDIT:** Would the following definitions for subgroup and left coset also work?

$\forall G, H, *:[Group(G,*) \land Group(H,*) \implies [H\le G \iff H\subseteq G]]$

$\forall G, H, *, x: [Group(G,*)\land Group(H,*) \land H\le G \land x\in G$

$ \implies \forall a: L(a,H,G,*,x) \iff \forall b:[b\in a \iff \exists c\in H: b=x*c]]$

Comment: I think we should use symbolic language only for teaching a computer.
This is ridiculous because it is just a substitution of human language to symbols; nothing new is here.

Comment: It is actually for use in a computerized formal system, but I didn't want to stray from standard definitions. I just want to know if these are precisely equivalent to those used by experts in the field before proceeding with my project. I have found the definitions given in online notes to be a bit ambiguous and wasn't sure that I had captured their essence with these formalizations.

Comment: I am not sure how you mean $(G,*)$ to be a statement which can imply things.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Good point. How about an is-a-group predicate Group(G, *)? Or just Group(G) assuming the binary operator will always be symbolized by *.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft See edited version.

Comment: I think you want a binary predicate $Group(G, *)$ instead of just a predicate on $G$; the same set can have multiple group operations on it, even at the same time.

Comment: The definition of subgroup seems a little off. Assuming you have a predicate that defines $g^{-1}$ (which seems quite needful in this context), I would then say 

$$H \leq G \iff H \subseteq G \land \forall h_1, h_2 \in H: {h_1}^{-1}*h_2 \in H$$

Comment: Also your updated 'left coset' definition is wrong: it allows $S \subset xH$ (consider $S = \{\}$ and apply your definition). Instead you want, for the final clause:
$$[L(S,H,G,x) \iff (a\in S \iff \exists b\in H: a=x*b)]$$

You then don't need to stipulate that $S\subset G$ (because that already follows from closure); just that $Group(G, *) \land x \in G \land H \leq G$.

Comment: @ChasBrown See the definition at ProofWiki https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Coset#Left_Coset  You are right about S ={ }. Have deleted that alternative. Thanks!

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't plan any to do any proofs that with multiple group operations. But I should mention it as possibility. Thanks.

Comment: @DanChristensen That's not my point. My point is that "Is a group" isn't a property of sets, it's a property of sets *with operations*. E.g. it doesn't even make sense to ask whether $\{0, 1\}$ is a group.

Comment: @DanChristensen: Again, in your Coset definition, it redundant to stipulate $b \in G$; because if $\exists c \in H: b = x * c$, then by closure, we must already have $b \in G$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber The Group*(G) predicate can be interpreted as: G is a set with binary operator * that is closed on G, etc.

Comment: @DanChristensen Ah, so it *is* implicitly a binary relation?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Looks explicit to me: $\forall a,b\in G: a*b\in G.$

Comment: @DanChristensen Sorry, I meant the "Group" predicate itself: "$Group^*(G)$" really means "$Group(*, G)$".

Comment: @NoahSchweber Again, I won't be considering proofs with multiple operators, so I don't think it is necessary for the group operator to be a kind of variable as you seem to be suggesting.

Comment: @DanChristensen OK, does "$Group^*(\{0, 1\})$" hold or not? Keeping in mind that that's both a set of real numbers, and the usual underlying set for the cyclic group with two elements . . .

Comment: Even worse, we frequently consider $\mathbb{R}^\times$ as a group with multiplication, and $\mathbb{R}$ as a group with addition (similarly additive groups of matrices, and multiplicative ones like $SO_n(\mathbb{R})$). But if we don't separately specify the group operations, then this means that $\mathbb{R}^\times$ satisfies your definition for being a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$!

Comment: @NoahSchweber As in my proposed definition, Group*({0, 1}) would mean that $\forall a, b \in \{0,1\}: a*b \in \{0,1\}$, etc.

Comment: @DanChristensen Yes, and I'm asking whether it is the case that that is true. Is $\{0, 1\}$ (say) closed under "$*$"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think I see the problem. Group*(G) does NOT mean that G on its own is a group. I will be sure to emphasize that. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @ChasBrown I agree that $b \in G$ is redundant in my definition of a coset. I have removed it. Thanks for your input!

Comment: To tag on to Noah's comments, a common problem I might want to answer is "how many non-isomorphic groups are there on the set $G = \{a,b,c,d\}$?" (FYI, the answer is $2$). In that case, we will want $*$ to have the quality of being a variable in your formulas.

Your original question was: 'Do they conform to the standard definitions?'. The standard definitions are designed to answer this sort of problem; so your formulation should as well; and that is the gist of Noah's comments (IMHO).

Comment: @ChasBrown I understand that and will it keep that in mind should I venture into more advanced topics. It should be an easy patch. Currently, I am planning to cover only the minimum theory to prove Lagrange's Theorem. To initially simplify matters, it seems to be common practice in introductory notes on group theory to consider only a single group operator in proofs. So much so that the symbol for the group operators is often omitted altogether, e.g. xy instead of x*y or x+y. Thanks again.

Comment: That's fine; but just note that your question was not 'what formulation of group theory is sufficient to prove Lagrange's theorem?'. It was 'Do [my definitions] conform to the standard definition? [...] I want to be sure I have captured the essence of these concepts before proceeding with my project'. Ask for what you want!

Comment: I have to admit I'm confused why you want to adopt a framework which you know you will have to patch down the road, but that's fair (although I think you should edit the question to clarify exactly what you want your definitions to be satisfactory *for*, as per Chas' comment). For what it's worth, one particular example of a context where this will be very unsatisfactory is reasoning about fields, where we often argue about the additive group of a field and the multiplicative group of its units simultaneously. (There are plenty of others as well, of course.)

Comment: A minor patch as I said. See edit.

Comment: @DanChristensen Yeah, it's definitely a minor patch - it just strikes me as a good idea from a design perspective to make these minor patches early on, if they're foreseeable.

Comment: Comments on edit?

Comment: Can you clarify anything about the computer system?

Comment: @djechlin Essentially, it's a proof checker. It is available as freeware at my website.

Comment: How will you express the assertion "$x^{-1}* a = b \iff a = x * b$"? Is that even expressible (let alone provable) in your system?

Comment: @ChasBrown As $inv(x)*a=b \iff a=x*b$ where $inv: G\to G$ and $inv(x)*x=x*inv(x)=e$. Such a function can be shown to exist on every group $(G,*)$ with identity $e$.

Comment: @ChasBrown And yes, it is provable in my system.

Comment: Ah. I did not realize that your system already informally encodes all of ZFC.

Comment: So when you say "$x∗y=z$" in the context of "$Group(G,∗)$", is that shorthand for saying "$∗(x,y)=z$, where $∗:G×G→G$"? Or are you saying something else; e.g. the string of symbols "$x∗y$" may be replaced with the symbol "$z$"? Or some other thing?

Comment: @ChasBrown In my system, I formally define a function $f: X\to Y$ as follows: $\forall a \in X: f(a)\in Y$. From this we can infer that $\forall a \in X: \exists b\in Y: b=f(a)$.